# Image plot function with aspect ratio 1 and ticks in axes

Tags: r

Given a squared matrix M, how can we plot it so that the aspect ratio is 1 and the axes are shown correctly?

I'm looking for this:

```
M <- t(replicate(50,sample(50, replace=TRUE)))
image(1:dim(M)[1], 1:dim(M)[1], M, col= gray((0:32)/32), asp=1)
```

[image]
But with the axes re-scaled to fit the image.

Comment: Do you mean something like add an axis with values from 1 to 50? If so, use `axis(1,1:50,1:50)` and add `axes=F` or `xaxt="n"` in the image function to suppress the axis and/or the tick labels.

Comment: Besides, I would like to remove the padding between the y axis and the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change values at the axis you can use the `axis` function and add `axes=F` or `xaxt="n"` in the image function to suppress the axis and/or the tick labels first.

```
image(1:dim(M)[1], 1:dim(M)[1], M, col= gray((0:32)/32), asp=1)
axis(1,1:50,1:50) # add a new x-axis
axis(2,1:50,1:50, pos=0) # add a y-axis with the coordinate zero.
```